# JavaFX window in terminal from RaspberryPI over SSH

Tags: java, ssh, javafx-2, raspberry-pi, java-8

I have no problem with running `JavaFX` window application directly on Pi in terminal(without startx GUI), but in the same app over `SSH`, there is no window showing in terminal. It looks like app is running but nothing shows up. I followed this instructions:
([see docs)](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/OpenJFX+on+the+Raspberry+Pi)

and this video:

([See Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uG4YjRDL8Dg))

How to make `javaFX` app window appear over `SSH` in terminal like?

Comment: did you tried to set DISPLAY variable?

Comment: Ok, i was trying with ssh -X and now i have:

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '192.168.1.10:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

192.168.1.10 is my PC local ip.

What now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess exporting the display may help. Try runnung this one in ssh:

```
export DISPLAY=<remote_pc_ip>:<smth.smth>
```